# Is there a way to register a callback function when the ethnet/wlan configuration changes?

Tags: linux

For example I have a board PC, at first it has on its eth0 a static IP I gave it. Then I connect it with a router, the router gives the eth0 a dynamic IP (dhcpc gives my eth0 a ip).
Can I register a callback function after this change? Currently the only thing I can think is to write a loop function to watch if the configuration has been changed or not. But a callback function is possible?

Comment: Which software do you use to configure the respective interface? `ifconfig`, `ip`, `dhclient`, `dhcpcd`, `systemd-networkd`, `netctl`, `NetworkManager`...?

Comment: @RichardNeumann dhcpclient

Comment: There's even low level `ip monitor address` that would work whatever the high level tool used

Comment: @A.B Nice, many thnx